# How do I to set different color background in a photo gallery?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have six images my photo gallery that users are able to horizontally scroll through using arrow buttons. Right now, the background color is set to one color so as you scroll, each image displays against the same background color. I want the background color to be different for each image as users scroll through them. I tried adding a new div class called “bk” inside each “gallery-image” class.  And in the CSS, I gave each “bk” a different background color in the CSS but this approach did not work. Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.

```js
const images = [...document.querySelectorAll('.image')];

// popup

const popup = document.querySelector('.popup');
const closeBtn = document.querySelector('.close-btn');
const imageName = document.querySelector('.image-name');
const largeImage = document.querySelector('.large-image');
const imageIndex = document.querySelector('.index');
const leftArrow = document.querySelector('.left-arrow');
const rightArrow = document.querySelector('.right-arrow');

let index = 0; // will track our current image;

images.forEach((item, i) => {
    item.addEventListener('click', () => {
        updateImage(i);
        popup.classList.toggle('active');
    })
})

const updateImage = (i) => {
    let path = `img/img${i+1}.png`;
    largeImage.src = path;
    imageName.innerHTML = path;
    imageIndex.innerHTML = `0${i+1}`;
    index = i;
}

closeBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    popup.classList.toggle('active');
})

leftArrow.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if(index > 0){
        updateImage(index - 1);
    }
})

rightArrow.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if(index < images.length - 1){
        updateImage(index + 1);
    }
})



const setPopupImage = index => {
  
  popup.classList.toggle('active');
}
setPopupImage(0);
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*:focus {
  outline: none;
}

body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: #ff7a2d;
  font-family: 'roboto', sans-serif;
}

.gallery {
  width: 80%;
  height: 90vh;
  max-width: 1600px;
  max-height: 800px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.gallery-image {
  width: 30%;
  height: calc(50% - 20px);
  min-width: 300px;
  min-height: 200px;
  margin: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  transition: 1s;
}



.popup {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0);
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background:pink;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: 5;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 1s;
  opacity: 0;
}




.popup.active {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
  opacity: 1;
}

.popup.active .close-btn,
.popup.active .image-name,
.popup.active .index,
.popup.active .large-image,
.popup.active .arrow-btn {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity .5s;
  transition-delay: 1s;
}

.top-bar {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  background: turquoise;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-weight: 300;
}


.image-name {
  opacity: 0;
}


.close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 35px;
  right: 70px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.arrow-btn {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: none;
  background: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.left-arrow {
  left: 10px;
}

.right-arrow {
  right: 10px;
  transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(180deg);
}

.arrow-btn:hover {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.index {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  font-size: 80px;
  font-weight: 100;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  opacity: 0;
}

.large-image {
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
  object-fit: contain;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Image Popup</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>
<body>
    <div class="popup">
        

        <div class="top-bar">
            <p class="image-name">img1.png</p>
            <span class="close-btn">
                <img src="Graphics/gallery_icon.svg" width="50px" class="close">
            </span>
        </div>
    
        <button class="arrow-btn left-arrow"><img src="img/arrow.png" alt=""></button>
        <button class="arrow-btn right-arrow"><img src="img/arrow.png" alt=""></button>
    
        <img src="img/img1.png" class="large-image" alt="">
    
        <h1 class="index">01</h1>
    </div>
    
    <div class="gallery">
        <div class="gallery-image">
            <img src="img/img1.png" alt="" class="image">
            
        </div>
        <div class="gallery-image">
            <img src="img/img2.png" alt="" class="image">
            <div class="bk"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="gallery-image">
            <img src="img/img3.png" alt="" class="image">
        </div>
        <div class="gallery-image">
            <img src="img/img4.png" alt="" class="image">
        </div>
        <div class="gallery-image">
            <img src="img/img5.png" alt="" class="image">
        </div>
        <div class="gallery-image">
            <img src="img/img6.png" alt="" class="image">
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="index.js"></script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Create CSS classes such as `.image-bk1 {background-color: red}`.  Add this class to "large-image" image and use JS to change the number just as with the path and index. (I don't know JS so can't create a working answer.)

Answer (score 0):

A rather simple solution would be to create an array of background colors whose number matches the number of images:

```
const backgroundColors = [
  '#fff',
  '#b2fa27',
  '#c2ba27',
  '#d27aee',
  '#e27a27',
  '#000',
];
```

Then, based on your HTML structure, you could create a function that updates the background color for each image:

```
const updateBackground = (i) => {
    popup.style.backgroundColor = backgroundColors[i];
}
```

Finally, you can call this function when you initialize your popup and in the click events:

```
leftArrow.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if(index > 0){
        updateImage(index - 1);
        updateBackground(index);
    }
})

rightArrow.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if(index < images.length - 1){
        updateImage(index + 1);
        updateBackground(index);
    }
})

const setPopupImage = index => {
  popup.classList.toggle('active');
  updateBackground(0);
}
```

Below is a full example that demonstrates the changes made above:

```js
const images = [...document.querySelectorAll('.image')];

// popup

const popup = document.querySelector('.popup');
const closeBtn = document.querySelector('.close-btn');
const imageName = document.querySelector('.image-name');
const largeImage = document.querySelector('.large-image');
const imageIndex = document.querySelector('.index');
const leftArrow = document.querySelector('.left-arrow');
const rightArrow = document.querySelector('.right-arrow');

const backgroundColors = [
    '#fff',
  '#b2fa27',
  '#c2ba27',
  '#d27aee',
  '#e27a27',
  '#000',
]

let index = 0; // will track our current image;

images.forEach((item, i) => {
    item.addEventListener('click', () => {
        updateImage(i);
        popup.classList.toggle('active');
    })
})

const updateImage = (i) => {
    let path = `img/img${i+1}.png`;
    largeImage.src = path;
    imageName.innerHTML = path;
    imageIndex.innerHTML = `0${i+1}`;
    index = i;
}

const updateBackground = (i) => {
    popup.style.backgroundColor = backgroundColors[i];
}

closeBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    popup.classList.toggle('active');
})

leftArrow.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if(index > 0){
        updateImage(index - 1);
        updateBackground(index);
    }
})

rightArrow.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if(index < images.length - 1){
        updateImage(index + 1);
        updateBackground(index);
    }
})



const setPopupImage = index => {
  
  popup.classList.toggle('active');
  updateBackground(index);
}
setPopupImage(0);
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*:focus {
  outline: none;
}

body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: #ff7a2d;
  font-family: 'roboto', sans-serif;
}

.gallery {
  width: 80%;
  height: 90vh;
  max-width: 1600px;
  max-height: 800px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.gallery-image {
  width: 30%;
  height: calc(50% - 20px);
  min-width: 300px;
  min-height: 200px;
  margin: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  transition: 1s;
}



.popup {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0);
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background:pink;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: 5;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 1s;
  opacity: 0;
}




.popup.active {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
  opacity: 1;
}

.popup.active .close-btn,
.popup.active .image-name,
.popup.active .index,
.popup.active .large-image,
.popup.active .arrow-btn {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity .5s;
  transition-delay: 1s;
}

.top-bar {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  background: turquoise;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-weight: 300;
}


.image-name {
  opacity: 0;
}


.close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 35px;
  right: 70px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.arrow-btn {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: none;
  background: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.left-arrow {
  left: 10px;
}

.right-arrow {
  right: 10px;
  transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(180deg);
}

.arrow-btn:hover {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.index {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  font-size: 80px;
  font-weight: 100;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  opacity: 0;
}

.large-image {
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
  object-fit: contain;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Image Popup</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>
<body>
    <div class="popup">
        

        <div class="top-bar">
            <p class="image-name">img1.png</p>
            <span class="close-btn">
                <img src="Graphics/gallery_icon.svg" width="50px" class="close">
            </span>
        </div>
    
        <button class="arrow-btn left-arrow"><img src="img/arrow.png" alt=""></button>
        <button class="arrow-btn right-arrow"><img src="img/arrow.png" alt=""></button>
    
        <img src="img/img1.png" class="large-image" alt="">
    
        <h1 class="index">01</h1>
    </div>
    
    <div class="gallery">
        <div class="gallery-image">
            <img src="img/img1.png" alt="" class="image">
            
        </div>
        <div class="gallery-image">
            <img src="img/img2.png" alt="" class="image">
            <div class="bk"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="gallery-image">
            <img src="img/img3.png" alt="" class="image">
        </div>
        <div class="gallery-image">
            <img src="img/img4.png" alt="" class="image">
        </div>
        <div class="gallery-image">
            <img src="img/img5.png" alt="" class="image">
        </div>
        <div class="gallery-image">
            <img src="img/img6.png" alt="" class="image">
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="index.js"></script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your code works when the user clicks the forward or back arrows to change the color. However if the user clicks on the the  "close-btn" and clicks a different image from the gallery the background color does not change. It keep the color of the previous background. Any way to fix this?

Comment: @Megan you can add `updateBackground(i);` right after `updateImage(i);` when you add the image listeners in the `foreach` loop.

Comment: @Megan it would be nice to solve your assignment on your own by looking up information and trying different things, instead of posting each subtask as a separate question :)